# Determine time required to start a program in GNU/Linux?

Tags: linux, x86-64, timing, elf

In GNU/Linux, is it possible to determine the time required to start a program? Where "start" is defined as having executed load_elf_binary() (or some other applicable function). In particular I want to write a program that can do this. I.e. a program, given another program as input, and then determine that time, with as high accuracy as possible.

Edit: Forgot to specify the hardware is x86-64.

Comment: On non-deterministic hardware?

Comment: Sorry, the hardware is x86-64. I forgot to add that in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NASA uses 386 and older hardware because they are deterministic, caches and super-scalar technologies make 486s and newer processors non-deterministic.  It is thus non-trivial to determine the startup time.

Articles of interest:

- http://science.slashdot.org/story/10/09/27/1333204/the-ancient-computers-powering-the-space-race
- http://drum.lib.umd.edu/bitstream/1903/891/2/CS-TR-3768.pdf
- http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~markhill/racey.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_algorithm
- http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~tbergan/papers/wodet11-hammer.pdf